# Level Curves in multiple variabes

Tags: calculus, curves

I want to sketch some level curves to the function $f(x,y) = 3x^2 + 4xy  + 3y^2$. I have tried to set the equation to C but I'm not sure how to proceed.

I've gotten hints to substitute $u = x + y$ and $v = x - y$ but it doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think choosing arbitrary C values is going to be so easy to make level curves. The discriminant of your equation is negative and $z$ won't be negative for any combination (x,y) Here is a plot of your function: http://www.math.uri.edu/~bkaskosz/flashmo/graph3d/  It is essentially a 3D parabolic vase. Horizontal cross sections are  ellipses

Comment: The hint means you should write the function in the form $a\cdot u^2 + b\cdot v^2$. That is easier to analyse.

Comment: @imranfat Yes, I was thinking of ellipses as well, but i cannot get the equation to resemble that of an ellipse.

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay thanks, I got that far aswell. But do we write the level curves in terms of u and v then (instead of x and y)?

Comment: As a start. Then you undo the basis change. It's just a rotation with a dilation, so it doesn't change the shape of anything.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah, when I do that I get $3x^2 + 2xy + 3y^2 = c$ which does not seem to make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On substituting $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$, you get, $$x=(u+v)/2$$ and $$y=(u-v)/2$$

Thus,

$$3x^2 + 4xy + 3y^2 = 3(u+v)^2/4 + (u+v)(u-v) + 3(u-v)^2/4$$

On simplification, it reduces to:

$$f(x,y)=g(u,v)=3(u^2+v^2)/2 + u^2-v^2 =( 5u^2 + v^2)/2$$

which is the equation of an ellipse in the $u-v$ plane.

The transformation is like rotating the $x-y$ axes and scaling it. So the cross section's shape wouldn't change.

Comment: Thank you very much! Although i got $(2u^2 + v^2)/2$ that helped me greatly.

Answer (score 1):

The curves are clearly elliptical.
To be more precise, notice that
$$
f(x,y) = (x,y)A\binom xy
\quad\text{where}\quad
A = \begin{bmatrix}3 & 2\\ 2& 3\end{bmatrix}
$$
Infinite many such $A$ exist, the one above is the one which is symmetric and hence diagonalizable.
Its eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = 1$ and $\lambda_2 = 5$, with respective eigenversors $v_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(1,-1)$ and $v_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(1,1)$.

This means that
\begin{align}
f(x,y)
= &
(x,y)
\begin{bmatrix}3 & 2\\ 2& 3\end{bmatrix}
\binom xy
\\
= &
(x,y)
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\ -1& 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0& 5\end{bmatrix}
\sqrt 2
{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\ -1& 1\end{bmatrix}}^{-1}
\binom xy
\\
= &
(x,y)
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} & \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}& \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0& 5\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}& \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\end{bmatrix}
\binom xy
\end{align}
Letting
$$\tag{1}
\begin{cases}
\hat x & = \displaystyle\frac{x-y}{\sqrt 2} \\
\hat y & = \displaystyle\frac{x+y}{\sqrt 2} \\
\end{cases}
$$
you have
$$
f(\hat x,\hat y) = \hat x^2 + 5\hat y^2
$$
therefore the level curves of $f$ in $(\hat x,\hat y)$ coordinates are solutions to
$$
\hat x^2 + 5\hat y^2 = C
$$
For $C<0$ you have no solutions, for $C=0$ you have only the origin, while for $C>0$
$$
\frac{\hat x^2}{(\sqrt C)^2} + \frac{\hat y^2}{(\sqrt{C/5})^2} = 1
$$
which are ellipses centered in the origin and with semiaxes $\sqrt C$ and $\sqrt{C/5}$ parallel to $\hat x$ and $\hat y$ respectively.
Basically they are all concentrical ellipses with ratio horizonal/vertical axis equal to $1/\sqrt 5$.

Notice that the change of variable $(1)$ is simply a rotation of $\frac{\pi}{4}$, so that in the original coordinates $(x,y)$ your curves are such ellipses rotated by $-\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: I really like this answer, very elegant.  Going to study it further.

Comment: Thanks @Karl, this is actually the usual way you study [conic sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section). Actually you don't need to go through all such computations to obtain basic info about the curves, you just have to study some invariant properties. You can find further info on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Cartesian_coordinates).